# Stack Overflow VB.net SQL Query

Tags: vb.net

I am getting through about 5000 queries before I get a stack overflow exception at the line where I call NewQuery2 again. Any ideas on what I can do to prevent this? I am trying to run about 40,000 queries.

```
Public Sub NewQuery2()
        Dim ID2 As String
        Try
            Dim ID As String
            ID = listBox1.Items(Next1)
            ID2 = ID
            Dim sql As String = "select INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD.MEMSTAT from INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD where INIT.MPI_MEMHEAD.MEMIDNUM = '" + ID + "'"
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()
            If dr.GetString(0) = "M" Then
                txtMerge.Text = txtMerge.Text + 1
            Else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 1   
            End If
            dr.Dispose
            cmd.Dispose
        Catch ex As Exception   
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + ex.Message + vbCrLf + ID2 
        End Try 
        Application.DoEvents
        If Next1 = listbox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
            conn.Dispose
        Else        
            Next1 = Next1 + 1
            NewQuery2()
        End If
    End SUb
```

Comment: why are you recursing instead of just looping on the listbox items?  you also need to start accepting the answers you get

Comment: Never use `Application.DoEvents` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx

Comment: I tried that originally. The problem is, there is a max connection limit and timeout on the oracle db which stops at 99. Thus I am recursing.

Comment: Nevermind. I see what you meant. I was originally looping in the connection. I have solved this issue based on your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're calling the method recursively from within itself and it's running out of stack space.  Try creating an external method instead that loops through your listbox and calls this method (without the call to itself, of course).